# CSS mess - text underneath image

Tags: html, css, image

No matter what I tried it doesn't work correctly.

Basically I have a list of images that fill up my entire div's width and height. 
Now I just want to add some captions right underneath each images. everything I tried either made the images all verticle in one line, etc.

Any kind of help I can get on this is greatly appreciated!

```
<div id="index-gallery" style="float:left; padding:5px; margin:10px 0 0 0;">
     <? $ires3 = mysql_query("select `id`,`mp4`,`cover` from `d2pxhd`.`videos` WHERE `duration`>'0' AND `active`='1' AND `suspended`='0' AND `add_date`<now() ORDER BY `add_date` DESC limit 24",$db);
         while ($img3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($ires3)) {  ?>     
          <a href="/?play=<?=base64_encode(preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $img3['id']));?>&start=1">
          <img style="margin:20px 2px;" width="118" height="100" border="0" src="<?=$img3['cover']."002.jpg";?>"></a>

   SUBTITLE HERE!!!

        <? } ?>
  </div>
```

Comment: Did you try to put the outer `div` inside the `while` loop?

Comment: yes I have... do you have any recommendations on what i can do? maybe I can try whatever you have in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this out.

**[JSFIDDLE EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dWM3E/)**

**HTML**

```
<div id="index-gallery">
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://movingimages.files.wordpress.com/2009/10/earth-simulator-offers-peaks-into-our-planetary-future.jpg?w=780" alt=""/>
        <p>My Caption here</p>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://movingimages.files.wordpress.com/2009/10/earth-simulator-offers-peaks-into-our-planetary-future.jpg?w=780" alt=""/>
        <p>My Caption here</p>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://movingimages.files.wordpress.com/2009/10/earth-simulator-offers-peaks-into-our-planetary-future.jpg?w=780" alt=""/>
        <p>My Caption here</p>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://movingimages.files.wordpress.com/2009/10/earth-simulator-offers-peaks-into-our-planetary-future.jpg?w=780" alt=""/>
        <p>My Caption here</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.item{
    width:200px;
    text-align:center;
    display:block;
    background-color: #ededed;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    float:left;
}

#index-gallery{
    width:465px;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this...

**HTML/PHP**

```
<div id="index-gallery">
  <?php $ires3 = mysql_query("select `id`,`mp4`,`cover` from `d2pxhd`.`videos` WHERE `duration`>'0' AND `active`='1' AND `suspended`='0' AND `add_date`<now() ORDER BY `add_date` DESC limit 24",$db);
    while ($img3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($ires3)) : ?>

      <div class="img-box">
        <a href="/?play=<?=base64_encode(preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $img3['id']));?>&start=1">
          <img style="margin:20px 2px;" width="118" height="100" border="0" src="<?=$img3['cover']."002.jpg";?>">
        </a>
        <p>SUBTITLE HERE!!!</p>
      </div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

  <div class="clear-both"></div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#index-gallery {
  width:100%;
}

.img-box {
  float:left;
  padding:5px;
  margin:10px 0 0 0;
}

.img-box a, .img-box img {
  display:block;
}

.clear-both {
  clear:both;
}
```

**Fixed Number of Columns in Each Row** (for more consistence formatting)

```
<?php $cols = 4; ?>

<div id="index-gallery">
  <?php $ires3 = mysql_query("select `id`,`mp4`,`cover` from `d2pxhd`.`videos` WHERE `duration`>'0' AND `active`='1' AND `suspended`='0' AND `add_date`<now() ORDER BY `add_date` DESC limit 24",$db); ?>

   <?php while ($img3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($ires3)) : ?>

     <?php for($i=1; $i <= $cols; $i++) : ?>

        <div class="img-box">
          <a href="/?play=<?=base64_encode(preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $img3['id']));?>&start=1">
            <img style="margin:20px 2px;" width="118" height="100" border="0" src="<?=$img3['cover']."002.jpg";?>">
          </a>
          <p>SUBTITLE HERE!!!</p>
        </div>

        <?php if($i == $cols) : ?>
          <div class="clear-both"></div>
        <?php $i=1; endif; ?>

      <?php endfor; ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

  <div class="clear-both"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: this 90% work - for some reason the first row is not lined up properly, but everything after that lines up very well...

Comment: Do you know how many images each row will have? Is it a fixed number?

Comment: Also, do you have a url so I can see it live?

Comment: yes, it is a fixed number, and i do not have any public url atm... thanks for your help btw

Comment: No problem! Just be careful when the subtitle takes up two lines instead of only one.

Comment: hahaha, oh man, but ok, i'll see if i can keep the subtitles short

Comment: Just try to add `<div style="clear:both;"></div>` after each row. I will update my answer in case you need this...